# How can I center my dropdown menu items?

Tags: css, menu, alignment, dropdown

I am working on a portfolio site template that will have a vertical, full-height menu to the left on displays of >= 1024px, and a horizontal, full-width, drop-down menu on mobile displays. The issue is that my drop-down menu items (the text itself, not the drop-down menu) is offset slightly to the right and not centered. I've played around with my CSS and I just can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone help?

```js
$('#nav-status').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#navigation').toggle();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/wood-dark.png");
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}


/*mobile rules*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  #nav-status {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  }
  ul {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
  }
  li h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  ul li {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 32px;
    padding: 2px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
  }
  li a:link,
  a:visited,
  a:active {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  li a:hover {
    color: #ba1d30;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}


/*desktop rules*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  #nav-status {
    display: none;
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  li h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  ul li {
    color: white;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 2px;
  }
  li a:link,
  a:visited,
  a:active {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  li a:hover {
    color: #ba1d30;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: italic;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <a href="#" id="nav-status"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/nerdcatkiss.png" alt="Kissy Cat"></a>
    <ul id="navigation">
      <li>
        <h1>Explore</h1>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Web Pages</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Games</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Productivity</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Project 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Here is a link to my Codepen in case that helps.](https://codepen.io/valsburger/pen/paNQym/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bit of padding to your `ul` element.

Just do `ul { padding : 0; }`. That's it.

Comment: You are amazing! I've been looking for 24 hours for a solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Haha, no problem, @Valsburger :) Mark as right answer, pls? :D

Comment: I have done so twice, I think because I only have 3 reputations it is not showing?

Comment: Ah, yes, I think so too. Never mind then. But do let me know once your site is up and running! :)